# Is there a good ETL framework for data warehouse in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, etl

I have investigated [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) and [Azkaban](https://azkaban.github.io/), but I think they are only used to schedule some jobs.

DW often need large of jobs to schedule, and is there a good framework for it?

Answer (score 4):

You can Use Pentaho data integration tool . Check this out. http://www.pentaho.com/product/data-integration

Answer (score 0):

You may also check **Talend** for Data integration in hadoop based warehouse. It offers graphical tools to create data intgeration flow between the hadoop components and it is opensource too.

please check http://www.talend.com/resource/hadoop-tools.html